# Is a truly p2p ledger (cryptocurrency) possible?

Tags: encryption, cryptocurrency

Is a truly p2p ledger possible, where there is no need for a third party (or a number of third parties) to verify ledgers.

Probably a system where the two parties who don't trust each other can verify each others ledger and then perform a transaction. If one of the parties is foul playing then the other party would not proceed with the transaction, cause that will make all his future transactions invalid.

Comment: Would you care to define the functional and security goals of the desired ledger?